# The 'valueForKeyPath:' function is not supported

Tags: swift, realm

Under *Array Operations* in [the Realm NSPredicate cheatsheet](https://news.realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) it states that we can make a query that targets a specific element in a `List` via `NSPredicate`. However, I always get a *"The 'valueForKeyPath:' function is not supported."* exception when I try the following.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let persons = realm.objects(Person.self)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "orders[0].created == $created")
persons.filter(predicate.withSubstitutionVariables(["created": Date()]))
```

I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 targeting iOS 9.0 with Realm 2.8.2

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Realm's [`NSPredicate` Cheatsheet](https://news.realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) covers *all* functionality supported by `NSPredicate`. Functionality supported by Realm is called out via a pink dot alongside a given entry. Array operations are [not yet supported](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1490) (as of Realm Swift v2.8.2).

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way to express that predicate. You could resort to storing the value of interest separately in a non-list property (either instead of, or as well as, being stored in the list), or you could use Swift's closure-based filtering instead. There are trade-offs to each, so it's hard to say which would be preferable for your case.